# MLflow Deployment on Databricks: File Not Found Error During Inference

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow, mlops

I'm currently facing a challenge with querying a model deployed on Databricks using MLflow. The model which is implemented as a Python function reads a JSON file, performs operations leveraging libraries like Spacy and NLTK, and returns an output.

Here's a simplified version of the deployment code:

```
def query_process_helper(input):
  with open('my_file.json', 'r') as j:
      data = json.loads(j.read())
  # Perform some processing and store the result in output
  return output


def query_processing(model_input):
    return query_process_helper(model_input)

mlflow_artifact_path = 'my_files' # I've ensured this location has my_file.json

with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        artifact_path=mlflow_artifact_path,
        python_model=query_processing,
        input_example=pd.DataFrame({'text': [sample_input]}),
        pip_requirements=['spacy==3.7.2','nltk==3.8.1'],
        artifacts={
        "my_file.json": mlflow_artifact_path
        }
    )
```

Error Message: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_files/my_file.json'`.

The model registration and the endpoint creation seem to be successful; no errors are reported in the build and service logs on Databricks.

I've also looked at [this](https://community.databricks.com/t5/machine-learning/register-mlflow-custom-model-which-has-pickle-files/td-p/7290) post but the accepted solution provided did not resolve my issue. I'm aiming to receive a direct response from the endpoint without explicitly loading the model again.

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to this would be greatly appreciated.